# Set Theory and Function Questions.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have two separate questions and have attempted them but I don't know if they're correct. I just guessed. I would like to know the method of working each one out please.

**
Explain when the following are true:

i) A ∪ B = A

ii) |A  –  B|  =  |A| **

For i) would it be that B is a subset of A?
ii) would B be the empty set?

**c)  For  each  of  the  following,  where  f:  Z→Z,  state  whether  f  is  1-1  (injective),  onto (surjective), both (bijective) or neither and explain your answer.

i) f(x) = 2x

ii) f(x) = ABS(x)

iii)  f(x) =  x+1 **

For i) would it be injective?
ii) I wouldn't know how to work this out.
iii) bijective

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer for (i) of the first problem is right, but not quite for (ii) - what is $\{1, 2\}-\{3\}$?

For (c): (i) and (iii) are right. For (ii), think about it this way:

- **Injectivity**: Can you think of two numbers with the same absolute value? (I presume that's what "ABS" means.)
- **Surjectivity**: What do you know about the absolute value of a number (e.g., what *can't* the absolute value of something be)?

Comment: Wouldn't  {1,2} - {3} be the empty set? I am sorry I am still confused

Comment: @user44836 Re-read the definition of set subtraction, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement (note that they use "$A\setminus B$" instead of "$A-B$"; this is in fact the more common notation, but in my answer I matched your notation for convenience).

Answer (score 0):

Your given answers are correct except for the (ii). The correctness of (ii) depends on the definition of $A-B$.

If it's the normal set minus ($A-B$ being elements in $A$ that is not in $B$) the answer is that it's true when $B$ is disjoint from $A$, but it can be true otherwise as well given that the notation $|A|$ means cardinality.

For your functions (i) and (iii) are both injective which is quite obvious, but only (iii) is surjective (the first is not because it will only take even values so it will for example never take the value $1$). The function (ii) is neither as it would never take the value $-1$ (which make it not surjective) and also $f(1) = 1 = f(-1)$ which make it not injective either.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for clarifying the answer to the ABS related q. I'm sorry but can u please explain the set theory question again? The one about |A-B| = |A|? I'm afraid I didn't understand  your explanation.